# Connect to CentOS httpd server running on VMware Player?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, centos, apache-http-server, vmware-player

I have a virtual LAMP machine set up with 32-bit CentOS 5.5 running on VMWare Player. It's being hosted on a Win 7 64-bit machine running a bridged network connection. Everything seems OK on the guest OS, as I can navigate to http://localhost and get the CentOS Apache 2 test page. However, I can not access the web server from a browser on the host OS through the IP address of the guest OS, which is the point of setting this up in the first place. I can successfully ping from host to guest (there is no firewall on the guest OS) too.

The image file for CentOS was downloaded from here (only used part 1 of 2):

http://virtual-machine.org/vmware-image-centos-55-i386-download

So is this something weird in the Apache conf or some hidden setting I'm missing in VMWare Player?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this recently, and it turned out to be a firewall issue. The default iptables blocked any incoming port (except ssh).

Here's an intro on iptables if you're not familiar with it: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables

And you need to make sure to at least allow port 80 incoming.

Comment: Yes, this has caught me before with CentOS - very annoying!

Comment: +1 for you buddy! you belong to ServerFault world :) I am a developer so server stuff is not in top of my mind when it comes to IPTables, etc even though I know what it is. I digged through VMWare kb, support and ServerFault, none pointed this setting as far as my search goes. More power to you!

Answer (score 4):

This is a firewall issue, so if you want to fix it quickly then temporarily stop `iptables` by giving the following command:

```
service iptables stop
```

Then check by running apache in host browser.

You can also add port 80 and 443 to `iptables`:

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Do that before commit and restart service. This way you can keep the firewall running and allow these to be be pinged from outside.

Answer (score 1):

This firewall issue can be fixed easily via webmin.

Just open

```
http://{YOUR-SERVER-IP:10000/
```

Then navigate to Networking → Linux Firewall. Then you should add a rule or edit one of predefined rules (like the one for 22 port) and save. At last click on Apply Configuration button.